# mobile scrolling event : an animation when I scrolling the screen

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, scroll, touch

I want to do an animation when the scrollTop in a certain value(like 500).

I used CSS3 and some event listener to finish this animation.

this is javascript code:

```
   $(window).on("scroll",animation);
   $(window).on("touchmove",animation);

   var oldscroll = 0;


   function animation(){
        var derection;

        if (oldscroll - $("body").scrollTop() < 0){
            derection = 1;
        }else if(oldscroll - $("body").scrollTop() > 0){
            derection = -1;
        }else{
            derection = 0;
        }

        if($("body").scrollTop() >=50 && derection == 1){
            $("nav ul").removeClass("animate_ul_back");
            $("nav ul").addClass("animate_ul");
            $("nav").addClass("animate_nav");
        }else if($("body").scrollTop() <= 50 && derection == -1){
            $("nav ul").removeClass("animate_ul");
            $("nav ul").addClass("animate_ul_back");
            $("nav").removeClass("animate_nav");
        }
        oldscroll = $("body").scrollTop();
    }
```

css code:

```
    .animate_nav{
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .animate_ul{
        -webkit-animation: ulmove 0.2s 0s;
        left:12px;
    }

    .animate_ul_back{
        -webkit-animation: ulmoveback 0.2s 0s;
        left:-46px;
    }


    @-webkit-keyframes ulmove{
        from{
            left:-46px;
        }
        to{
            left:12px;
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes ulmoveback{
        from{
            left:12px;
        }
        to{
            left:-46px;
        }
    }
```

html:

```
<nav>
     <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="logo_min"><img src="images/logo_animate.png"></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#" class="current">首页</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#">a</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#">b</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#">c</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

however,even in the browser(safari) of iphone(IOS7) the simple animate will be defer until the scroll finish.

I know the problem is the event listener --- scroll and touchmove.

How can I fix the problem.If a event Listener like scrolling exist?

I haved tried setTimeout, setInterval or requestanimationframe. They don't work when the document is scrolling and my finger has left the screen.

ths all first.

Comment: This problem got fixed. It seems something about compatibility between the beta version of IOS and webview of apps on system.